# Using Custom View Controllers to manage different portions of the same view hierarchy

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uikit, uiviewcontroller

The View controller programming guide states this regarding view controller's usage:

> Each custom view controller object you
>   create is responsible for managing all
>   of the views in a single view
>   hierarchy. In iPhone applications, the
>   views in a view hierarchy
>   traditionally cover the entire screen,
>   but in iPad applications they may
>   cover only a portion of the screen.
>   The one-to-one correspondence between
>   a view controller and the views in its
>   view hierarchy is the key design
>   consideration. **You should not use
>   multiple custom view controllers to
>   manage different portions of the same
>   view hierarchy**. Similarly, you
>   should not use a single custom view
>   controller object to manage multiple
>   screens worth of content.

I understand that if we use multiple custom view controller's to control the parts of a view (i.e. a view controller to manage subViews of a main view which in turn is managed by a view controller) the default methods like:

```
didReceiveMemoryWarnings
viewWillAppear
viewWillDisappear
viewDidUnload
```

etc. etc. will not be called.

Apart from this, is there any other solid reason why we should not be using multiple view controllers to manage the respective subviews of a view?

The documentation also provide an alternative solution which reads as:

> Note: If you want to divide a view
>   hierarchy into multiple subareas and
>   manage each one separately, use
>   generic controller objects (custom
>   objects descending from NSObject)
>   instead of view controller objects to
>   manage each subarea. Then use a single
>   view controller object to manage the
>   generic controller objects.

But there is no mention as to **why multiple view controllers** should not be preferred. My question is:

Why should not we prefer it this way?

I am concerned because I prefer using UIViewController's subclass to manage my views since I load them from nib each time and I segregate nibs for each view controllers. It becomes easy to cater the changes in later stages of the project. Is this wrong? Should I necessarily change my programming style, or is it ok if I go ahead with this approach?

Thanks,

Raj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I'd say "as long as it works", you can keep on doing like you do !
But to keep things "cleaner", I'd use my own objects.
Since ViewControllers are designed with other general features in mind (like working with navigation controllers and tab bar controllers), which makes it a bit "heavy" for a simple usage, like you do. 
Plus, like you mentioned, some events are only called when the viewController's view is added to the main window.

Can't you use your own objects with Interface Builder ? If you create one (or several) UIView IBOutlet(s), it should work the same.

Comment: Yes it can be done, I can create a NSObject subclass and designate it as a file's owner for that nib. But I was wondering if there are any other specific reasons of why not to do it this way. Your explanation of the object being "heavy" does suffice, as of now.

Comment: Well, I just think it's pretty much useless. Since the only reason you gave was to segregate them in IB, and that can be done with an NSObject. I don't think you will use any of UIViewController's methods, so why subclass this specific object ? I mean you could also subclass any other UIResponder subclass (like a UIView, or UIButton), but since the only interesting thing you use is the view IBOutlet, you don't need such a specific object.

Answer (score 0):

I have an app that does use two UIViewControllers on a single screen.  The child is a UITableViewController.  I don't rely on any of the UIViewController behavior of the child -- only the UITableViewController methods.  This is convenient because there are other cases where the child UITableViewController does manage the whole screen.  And in that case, it does use the UIViewController methods.  Questionable design?  Maybe.  It has worked fine for two years now.  But I'm not sure I would recommend the pattern.